# Saving states only saves partial of the fragment

Tags: android, bundle

I have a prroblem with saving the state of some parts of my app.

In the layout i have 5 `EditText` a `Button` and a `TextView`. When the user enters values and calculate (button click), the `TextView` is populated.

When orientation changes nothing happens, the views are passed on and works perfectly, however when i swipe (with my `ViewPager`) the state of the populated `TextView` is not being saved. I have 3 fragments and if i only swipe, say from the right to middle it is saved however if i swipe to the far left the `TextView` is unpopulated when i return to the fragment, the values entered in the `EditText` is saved.

My anticipation is that the process from the `onClick()` (which is doing calculations and populate the `TextView`) is not saved, how do i go by with this? I have tried following up on the guide on [Googles site](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) without any luck.

My code goes:

```
public class FuelConsumptionFragment extends Fragment implements OnClickListener {


View view;
int savedState = 0;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

}


@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    if (savedInstanceState != null) {

        savedState = savedInstanceState.getInt("curChoice", 0);

    }

}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putInt("curChoice", savedState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fuel_consumption, container, false);

    Button calculate_fuel = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.calculate_fuel);
    calculate_fuel.setOnClickListener(this);

    return view;

    }
```

Manifest:

```
<activity
            android:name="simcas.fartberegneren.MainActivity"
            android:icon="@drawable/fartberegneren"
            android:label="" 
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" >
</activity>
```

**Edit:** I have a vague idea that the inflation in `onCreateView` could be the problem, is this correct?

**Edit 2:** Just going around my code and realising that my "custom" adapter might be a part of the problem, the code goes:

```
public class MyAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

public MyAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);

}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return 3;
}


@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    switch (position) {
    case 0: return new SpeedZonesFragment();
    case 1: return new DistanceFragment();
    case 2: return new FuelConsumptionFragment();
    default: return null;
    }
}
}
```

Could this cause the issue? As i see i am creating a new `Fragment` when switching position, is the correct?

**Edit 3:** Code for the `onClick()`:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {

DecimalFormat format = new DecimalFormat("#.#");

InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);

EditText distance_entry_fuel = (EditText) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.distance_fuel);
EditText speed_a_entry_fuel = (EditText) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.speed_a_fuel);
EditText gas_a_use = (EditText) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.gas_use_a);
EditText speed_b_entry_fuel = (EditText) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.speed_b_fuel);
EditText gas_b_use = (EditText) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.gas_use_b);
EditText gas_price = (EditText) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.gas_price);

distance_entry_fuel.setRawInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL);
speed_a_entry_fuel.setRawInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL);
gas_a_use.setRawInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL);
speed_b_entry_fuel.setRawInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL);
gas_b_use.setRawInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL);
gas_price.setRawInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL);


distance_entry_fuel.clearFocus();
speed_a_entry_fuel.clearFocus();
gas_a_use.clearFocus();
speed_b_entry_fuel.clearFocus();
gas_b_use.clearFocus();

double moneySpend;
double timeArest;
double timeArest1;
double timeBrest;
double timeBrest1;
double totalTime;
double totalTimerest;

try {

    double distance = Double.parseDouble(distance_entry_fuel.getText().toString());
    double speedA = Double.parseDouble(speed_a_entry_fuel.getText().toString());
    double gasA = Double.parseDouble(gas_a_use.getText().toString());
    double speedB = Double.parseDouble(speed_b_entry_fuel.getText().toString());
    double gasB = Double.parseDouble(gas_b_use.getText().toString());
    double gasPrice = Double.parseDouble(gas_price.getText().toString());

    double gasUseA = (distance / gasA);
    double gasUseB = (distance / gasB);

    if (speedB > speedA) {

        if (gasUseB > gasUseA) {

            moneySpend = ((gasUseB - gasUseA) * gasPrice);

        }

        else {

            moneySpend = ((gasUseA - gasUseB) * gasPrice);

        }

        timeArest = (distance % speedA); // Calculate the remainder of A
        timeArest1 = ((timeArest / speedA) * 60); // Convert the remainder of A to minutes       
        timeBrest = (distance % speedB); // Calculate the remainder of B
        timeBrest1 = ((timeBrest / speedB) * 60); // Convert the remainder of B to minutes

        totalTime = (int)((distance / speedA) - (distance / speedB)); // Calculate the amount of hours saved            

        if (timeArest >= timeBrest) {   // Condition for calculating time

            totalTimerest = (timeArest1 - timeBrest1);

        }

        else {                          // opposite condition

            totalTimerest = ((timeArest1 - timeBrest1) + 60); // Make up for the negative number

        }           

    }

    else {

        if (gasUseB > gasUseA) {

            moneySpend = ((gasUseB - gasUseA) * gasPrice);

        }

        else {

            moneySpend = ((gasUseA - gasUseB) * gasPrice);

        }

        timeArest = (distance % speedA); // Calculate the remainder of A
        timeArest1 = ((timeArest / speedA) * 60); // Convert the remainder of A to minutes       
        timeBrest = (distance % speedB); // Calculate the remainder of B
        timeBrest1 = ((timeBrest / speedB) * 60); // Convert the remainder of B to minutes

        totalTime = (int)((distance / speedB) - (distance / speedA)); // Calculate the amount of hours saved

        if (timeBrest >= timeArest) {   // Condition for calculating time

            totalTimerest = (timeBrest1 - timeArest1);

        }

        else {                          // opposite condition

            totalTimerest = ((timeBrest1 - timeArest1) + 60); // Make up for the negative number

        }   
    }

    String minuteTotal = "";
    String hourTotal = "";

    if (totalTimerest == 1) {

        minuteTotal = " minut";

        }

    else { 

        minuteTotal = " minutter";

    }

    if (totalTime == 1) {

       hourTotal = " time";

    }

    else {

        hourTotal = " timer";

    }

    String moneySpendOnGas;

    String distanceText = "Over en strækning på " + format.format(Double.parseDouble(distance_entry_fuel.getText().toString())) + " km";
    String gasUsedA = "Bruger du " + format.format(gasUseA) + " liter benzin, ved en gennemsnitsfart på " + speedA + " km/t.";
    String gasUsedB = "Bruger du " + format.format(gasUseB) + " liter benzin, ved en gennemsnitsfart på " + speedB + " km/t.";

    if (totalTime > 0) {

        if (totalTimerest > 0) {

            moneySpendOnGas = "Det koster dig " + format.format(moneySpend) + " kr at komme " + (int)totalTime + hourTotal + " og " + (int)totalTimerest + minuteTotal + " hurtigere frem.";

        }

        else {

            moneySpendOnGas = "Det koster dig " + format.format(moneySpend) + " kr at komme " + (int)totalTime + hourTotal + " hurtigere frem.";

        }

    }

    else {

        moneySpendOnGas = "Det koster dig " + format.format(moneySpend) + " kr at komme " + (int)totalTimerest + minuteTotal + " hurtigere frem.";

    }

    TextView distance_text_fuel = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.distance_text_fuel);
    distance_text_fuel.setText(distanceText);
    TextView gas_used_a = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.gas_used_a);
    gas_used_a.setText(gasUsedA);
    TextView gas_used_b = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.gas_used_b);
    gas_used_b.setText(gasUsedB);
    TextView money_spend = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.money_spend);
    money_spend.setText(moneySpendOnGas);
}

catch (NumberFormatException e) {

    DialogFragment alert = new EntryAlertDialog();
    alert.show(getFragmentManager(), "Alert");

}

}
```

Comment: try to call `ViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(2)`

Comment: @vmironov: While this actually worked, it didnt really resolve the problem with saving the states, so if fx i had 10 fragments in the viewpager it would use a tremendous amount of memory right?

Comment: yep. You have to implement `onSaveInstanceState` and then properly restore fragment state

Comment: I have the `onSaveInstanceState` but im guessing not correctly, what is the correct way to save the fragment state when the activity remains the same?

Comment: can you post your `onClick` method?

Comment: It is quite long, but of course, i have edited in my custom adapter which might be the responsible for the error :-)

Comment: `Could this cause the issue? As i see i am creating a new Fragment when switching position, is the correct?` that possibly is the issue, but to confirm, put a `Log.d("MyTAG", "getItem position " + position);` to check exactly when the system is creating a new fragment and when it's re-using existing ones.

Comment: I am going to look further into what @Budius said and then going to edit it into the post as it might be usefull to others if it is the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can force `TextView` to save its state as well as `EditText` do. Just call `TextView.setFreezesText(true)` or add `android:freezesText="true"` for a `TextView` tag in your layout file.